# Kotlin multiplatform projects run common module test in IDEA

Tags: unit-testing, intellij-idea, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I am using kotlin multiplatform project with js/jvm subprojects.
I used to have unit tests in jvm subproject (annotated using kotlin test annotations) and I easily ran tests using rightclick + Run 'xxx' test using junit. That option is not possible once I move those tests to common module instead.

I can still run tests using command line gradle and I even managed to create working Run configuration that worked, but I am missing that simple "right click to run" on class or even specific test method for convenience.

Is there any way to achieve that in project?

Thanks!

Comment: Just ran into the same problem here after converting my project into a multiplatform project. Any luck?

Comment: Having same problem, IntelliJ 2018.2.5, Kotlin plugin 1.3.0-release-IJ2018.2-1

Comment: Same here. Problem still persists in Kotlin 1.3.10.

Comment: Problem still persists in Kotlin 1.3.21 and IntelliJ 2019.1

Answer (score 2):

Which Kotlin version do you use? There was [a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-20363) with test gutters in 1.2.60, but it is fixed in the very next release which is expected to be at the beginning of the next week.

It actually should work as you described, so if it's not the version with the bug, then it's better to submit it.

Comment: Thanks for the link! At the moment I am at 1.2.60, but it wasn't working even before, when I was at 1.2.31 or 1.2.40 I think.

Comment: I am on `1.2.61` and this problem still occurs. By the very next release, do you mean `1.2.70` (this seems to be listed as 'Fix in builds' in the issue you linked to)?

Comment: Seems like we've already discussed it in the issue :)

I meant exactly 1.2.61, the build number 1.2.70 means that it will be also there, and that's it. Talking about issue fields, `target version` usually contains more relevant information in such a context, while `fix in builds` is rather supposed to be for internal usage.

Comment: Problem still persists in Kotlin `1.3.21` and IntelliJ 2019.1

Comment: Do you mean missing action or rather [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-29908) problem?