# How to configure JUnit 5 in a Kotlin multiplatform project using Gradle and IntelliJ?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin, junit5, kotlin-multiplatform

### JUnit 4 (working)

The Kotlin multiplatform template in IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.3 (Community Edition) relies on JUnit 4.12 in `build.gradle` for the JVM part of the project:

```
plugins {
    id 'kotlin-platform-jvm' version '1.2.61'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
    expectedBy project(":TestMulti-common")
    testCompile "junit:junit:4.12"
    testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test"
    testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit"
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
sourceCompatibility = "1.8"
```

Using this template, I can add tests to the common part of the project and the *tests are recognized by IntelliJ*: a 'Run' icon shows up in the margin of the source files and tests can be run through the context menu.

### JUnit 5 (tests not properly recognized in IntelliJ)

**How can I achieve a similar setup using JUnit 5?**

Of note, I am using Gradle 4.10 (some older examples use [`junit-platform-gradle-plugin`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.platform/junit-platform-gradle-plugin) which [has been deprecated since Gradle 4.6](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1317)). Documentation on how to set this up is outdated and scarce:

- As shown above, the default project template built in IntelliJ does not use JUnit 5.
- The JUnit team [provides examples, but not for Kotlin multiplatform](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples).

When I try to set up the `build.gradle` for the JVM part of the project [based on the JUnit 5 Gradle example](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/blob/master/junit5-jupiter-starter-gradle/build.gradle), *I can run tests using Gradle*, but **IntelliJ does not seem to recognize my tests**.

```
plugins {
    id 'kotlin-platform-jvm' version '1.2.61'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
    expectedBy project(":TestMulti-common")

    testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test"
    testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit5"

    testCompile('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.1')
    testCompile('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.3.1')
    testRuntime('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.1')
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging {
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
    }
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
sourceCompatibility = "1.8"
```

Oddly enough, sometimes test results appear in IntelliJ's test results when running `gradle test` on the JVM project, but when rerunning the tests the message *"Test events were not received"* shows up. The 'Run' icons in the margin never appear in source files and neither do the test options in the context menu.

Other people seem to have similar issues, but it is unclear whether or not these are the same/related or have been resolved since:

- [Junit 5 and Gradle 4.6 check task shows "Test events were not received"](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000152524-Junit-5-and-Gradle-4-6-check-task-shows-Test-events-were-not-received-)
- [junit5 tests are not shown in test view](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-188404)
- [No "Run" icon on the left for tests in common part of a multi-platform project](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-20363)
- [Kotlin multiplatform projects run common module test in IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51910553/590790)

The many different releases, outdated documentation, and similar issues make it hard to find more information about this problem.

Comment: As I am on Intellij IDEA Ultimate EAP... could you just try to use it too and look whether this specific behaviour is also there? I do not remember that I have encountered any strange behaviour using Junit5 with Intellij... and my `build.gradle` only differs in the following: instead of `testCompile` I have `testImplementation` and instead of `testRuntime` I have `testRuntimeOnly`. The rest is the same

Comment: @Roland Originally I was using `testImplementation` as well (as I believe this is the new way to write it). I only used `testCompile` since this is what the JUnit example listed (another example of outdated documentation :(). Neither work. Do you also have a multiplatform project though?

Comment: ah... forget it... oh dear... I read multi-module.... :-( will delete my comments again ;-)

Comment: @Roland Don't. It might be relevant. I will test again to use the same configuration but in a 'normal' (non-multiplatform) project to verify whether the issue occurs there as well or not (as you state).

Comment: well... the only relevant information is just that I've used `testImplementation` instead of `testCompile` and `testRuntimeOnly` instead of `testRuntime` and probably that I am using Intellij Ultimate EAP. But as I am not using a multiplatform-project (nor a multi-module project anymore ;-)), all my other comments are irrelevant now and this comment summarizes what was important ;-)

Comment: After some more debugging, I discovered that _removing_ the `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit` dependency from the JUnit 4 `build.gradle` causes the integration with IntelliJ to fail (no more run icons and test options in context menu). I subsequently tried adding `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit` to the JUnit 5 `build.gradle` rather than simply replacing it with `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit5`. The icons now show up, but test events are not received correctly. **This makes me believe the problem lies with `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit5`.**

Comment: @Roland No. The built-in template for Kotlin JVM does not use Gradle, so it seemed less trivial than I thought at first to quickly try this out.

Comment: hmmm... I do not use any `kotlin-test-junit5` (nor `kotlin.test`)-dependency ;-) So you might be right... I wanted to start with it, but if I read something like that I will probably just stick with Junit5 alone ;-)

Comment: In regards to rerunning the tests 'not working', [it seems this is 'by design'](https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-intellij-plugin/issues/33). This is since the task is up to date since no changes were made. To always see the test results in IntelliJ, [clean the tests first by running `gradle cleanTest test`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29428063/590790).

Comment: This is definitely special ;-) We should probably clean up some comments now... otherwise they end up in the chat... and I think they contain some valid information...

Comment: I also pinged somebody [in a related JetBrains YouTrack ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-20363). I will first await a response/sleep on it tonight and probably open up a new bug issue @ JetBrains tomorrow, condensing all we learned into a single bug report. On my end at least, I can now create an easy repro with the culprit being `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit5`. I checked the source difference between this and `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit` but have no clue how this could influence IntelliJ's test lookup.

Comment: Posted this [as a bug report on JetBrain's YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-26792).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug in IntelliJ as I described in the following YouTrack issue: [IntelliJ does not recognize JUnit 5 tests in Kotlin multiplatform project](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-26792).

In the latest version this is now working. I tried with Kotlin 1.3.71, the IntelliJ plugin 1.3.71-release-IJ2019.3-1, and JUnit 5.6.0.

Answer (score 1):

In my case IntelliJ IDEA upgrade disabled JUnit plugin, so I needed to enable it again (requires IDE restart):

[image: IntelliJ IDEA JUNit plugin needs to be enabled]